# Errors when running vim with the pyflakes plugin

Tags: python, vim, pyflakes

I'm playing with the [pyflakes plugin for vim](https://github.com/kevinw/pyflakes-vim) and now when I open a python file I get the error messages in the screenshot [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6114719/Screenshot.png)

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/kevinw/pyflakes-vim/issues/27

> You can recommend to users that they clone the pyflakes-vim repo with git clone --recursive or you can suggest after the fact to use git submodule update --init --recursive if pyflakes-vim is saved as a git submodule itself.

Or go to pyflakes-vim and:

```
git submodule init && git submodule update
```

The point is that pyflakes-vim needs a (fresh) local copy of pyflakes under `ftplugin/plugin/pyflakes` if the system-wide installed version is too old.

Answer (score 1):

Could be an issue with the version of Python you're running under vs. what the package you're using is looking for.  A quick google for "Module getChildNodes python" got me to the page for [Python compiler package](http://docs.python.org/library/compiler.html) which has one of those nice little "Deprecated" messages on it.  So it might be that the pyflakes plugin is out of synch with the version of Python  you have installed.  "Python -V" will show you what version you're running.

```
C:\projects\fun>python -V
Python 2.7.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this to solve my problem under the Mac OS X 10.9.5.

```
sudo easy_install pip
pip install pyflakes
```

Then I opened the python scripts again, no issues reported as this:

[image: Imported Error: No module named pyflakes]

Enjoy!

Robin

2015.01.30

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug in pyflakes and we cannot help you with this here.

Try filing an issue on [their git repository](https://github.com/kevinw/pyflakes-vim/issues).